# When does season 5 start?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does anyone have an idea or source of when season 5 starts or when ranked gets reset? I have been sitting here at Diamond V and Master. Someone said the 15th of January, but then the kickoff sale came out and now people are saying it'll reset between January 20-27th.

Comment: January 21st. (Source: http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/competitive/get-ready-2015-ranked-season)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been announced as the 21st of January.

Official announcement: http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/competitive/get-ready-2015-ranked-season